# Where is MKL (or other libraries) located in an Anaconda installation

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, intel-mkl

I have Anaconda3 with MKL installed.

I am trying to set the `BLAS_INCLUDE` and `BLAS_LIB` variables to install Caffe, but I don't know the appropriate paths. What are the paths that they are supposed to point to and how do I find those paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you installed Anaconda, on what OS, and the environment you are using (root (default) environment, or one you created). Note that for Miniconda, the directories will be similar, generally replacing `anaconda` with `miniconda`.

---

## Windows

The typical install path here is `C:\Anaconda` or `C:\Anaconda3` for the "All Users" installation, or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\Anaconda` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\Anaconda3` for the "Just for me" installation. I'll refer to these directories as `%ANACONDA_ROOT%` in the following.

#### Root environment

- Library directory: `%ANACONDA_ROOT%/Library/lib`
- Include directory: `%ANACONDA_ROOT%/Library/include`

#### Another environment

For packages installed into an environment that you create, the directories are the same, except that you need to add the `envs/env_name` directory into the middle of the path, where `env_name` is the name of the environment you created

- Include directory: `%ANACONDA_ROOT%/envs/env_name/Library/include`
- Library directory: `%ANACONDA_ROOT%/envs/env_name/Library/lib`

---

### macOS/Linux

The default installation path is `$HOME/anaconda` or `$HOME/anaconda3`, I'll use `$ANACONDA_ROOT` to mean this directory in the following. Note that your directory might be different (another common value is `/opt/conda`).

#### Root environment

- Library directory: `$ANACONDA_ROOT/lib`
- Include directory: `$ANACONDA_ROOT/include`

#### Another environment

For packages installed into an environment that you create, the directories are the same, except that you need to add the `envs/env_name` directory into the middle of the path, where `env_name` is the name of the environment you created

- Library directory: `$ANACONDA_ROOT/envs/env_name/lib`
- Include directory: `$ANACONDA_ROOT/envs/env_name/include`